# Inheritance in php with abstract methods

Tags: php

I try to inherit from an abstract class to an abstract class:

```
abstract class Android{
    public $description="unknown brand";
    public function __construct() {

    }
    public function get_description(){
        return $this->description;
    }    
    public abstract function cost();
}

abstract class FeaturesDecorator extends Android {
    public abstract function get_description();
}
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot make non abstract method Android::get_description() abstract in class FeaturesDecorator in C:\xampp\htdocs\jPlugin\DesignPatterns\Decorator\Decorator.php on line 65

why? what ruins the inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `get_description` is already defined and declared in your parent class, you can't make it abstract in the child.

Comment: In other languages you can.. cant it be overriden?